# Selecting subsets of rows surrounding events in another column

Tags: r, subset, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a data frame that includes a subset of data- specifically, chunks of rows flanking an event in another column.

Here's an example of my data. It includes data from two participants (identified by `id`), the timing of the `event` (1 = yes, 0 = no), and the variable of interest `x`.

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), event = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), x = c(-0.524745604197535, 0.56664753932467, 1.06326937193775, 
-1.74261927944691, -1.70220588525303, 0.788056468394497, -0.315524780669081, 
-1.09956621127396, 0.725332798657826, -0.821455118910762, -0.305075137324048, 
0.0975277444454113, -1.37607536240115, -1.1749745326815, -0.0254452552627888, 
0.0291714672416614, -0.560221734093268, -0.832517971223058, 1.01067311827293, 
-0.0101155699102594, -2.211772959964, -0.324879965548731, 0.189774016276101, 
-0.124110438315279, 0.87450859784393, 0.534102255268043, 0.483572995043595, 
0.717566852172195, 0.62058456685663, 0.100291898582953, -1.97147667641014, 
0.390331677978558, -2.44481260988607, -1.08221493718706, 1.282044558805, 
1.46339582810391, -0.388529539761603, -1.0347479743086, -0.244983560420757, 
-0.745529649917578, -0.581202927866314, -0.0468146194831979, 
0.353756786882484, 0.726051987010529, 0.785563528600549, 0.234591665330184, 
0.661859569057452, 0.718155884148953, 1.02606212190121, 0.35208377496606
)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to subset data so that the resulting data frame includes data from `x` that corresponds to the 2 rows on either side of the `event` (plus the event itself), so 5 rows for each event. For example:

[image]

**So the first question is** how to achieve this?

However, some of those rows will overlap. In the image above, I've created a cumulative id called `cum_id` which identifes each event. We can see that there are overlaps for some rows between events 2 and 3 (for participant 1), and for some rows between 1 and 2 (for participant 2). Similarly, the very first and last events are incomplete.

So I'd like to remove those events completely where there are overlaps and retain only the complete sets of rows with a preference for the event that occurs first.

So the final product should look like this, with the `cum_id` uniquely identifying the events for each person.

[image]

If it's not possible to remove the overlapping events, I suppose a second option would be to retain all of the rows, but the `cum_id` would prefer the event that occurs first, so that the second event would have an incomplete number of rows (eg, 4 instead of 5).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a 1 two rows before and two rows after each event with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
    df |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(cum_id = case_when(lag(lag(event)) == 1 ~ id,
                            lag(event) == 1 ~ id,
                            event == 1 ~ id,
                            lead(event) == 1 ~ id,
                            lead(lead(event)) == 1 ~ id,
                            .default = 0
                            )
         )
```

But the rest of your assignment eludes me. We can identify the rows from an event until the next one adding this line: `mutate(var2 = cumsum(row_number() == 1 | (event != dplyr::lag(event) & event != 0)))`

Comment: So the code you provided identifies the events, but it doesn't subset anything. IE it still has the same number of rows as my original df.

Comment: With the second mutate line I provided, it should be easy to get events that are shorted due to overlapping, then mark the event that overlaps the previous one, and filter it.